QT5multimedia not configure with my build image
ERROR: inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app-1.0.0-r0 do_configure: ExecutionError(‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-sm-linux/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/1.0.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.4174130’, 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-sm-linux/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/1.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.4174130
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are [‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtbase_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtcharts_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtdeclarative_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtmultimedia_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtnetworkauth_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtquick3d_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtquickcontrols2_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtquickcontrols_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtserialport_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.35.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-systemctl-native.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_250.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake-native_3.22.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_11.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘virtual:native:/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtdeclarative_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘virtual:native:/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/ninja/ninja_1.10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘virtual:native:/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot’, ‘virtual:native:/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot’]
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot:
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: [‘qtbase-native’, ‘qtbase’, ‘qtcharts’, ‘qtdeclarative’, ‘qtmultimedia’, ‘qtnetworkauth’, ‘qtquick3d’, ‘qtquickcontrols2’, ‘qtquickcontrols’, ‘qtserialport’, ‘glibc’, ‘systemd-systemctl-native’, ‘systemd’, ‘cmake-native’, ‘gcc-cross-aarch64’, ‘gcc-runtime’, ‘quilt-native’, ‘qtdeclarative-native’, ‘ninja-native’, ‘patch-native’, ‘pseudo-native’, ‘bzip2-native’, ‘zstd-native’, ‘ncurses-native’, ‘xz-native’, ‘zlib-native’, ‘curl-native’, ‘libpng’, ‘libxkbcommon’, ‘libjpeg-turbo’, ‘xcb-util-renderutil’, ‘zlib’, ‘libdrm’, ‘xcb-util-wm’, ‘libpcre2’, ‘glib-2.0’, ‘openssl’, ‘fontconfig’, ‘dbus’, ‘sqlite3’, ‘libxcb’, ‘libxext’, ‘vulkan-headers’, ‘icu’, ‘imx-gpu-viv’, ‘freetype’, ‘xcb-util-image’, ‘xcb-util-keysyms’, ‘shadow-native’, ‘opkg-utils’, ‘libpam’, ‘libseccomp’, ‘acl’, ‘shadow-sysroot’, ‘shadow’, ‘base-passwd’, ‘kmod’, ‘base-files’, ‘bash-completion’, ‘libcap’, ‘zstd’, ‘util-linux’, ‘libtool-native’, ‘attr-native’, ‘gnu-config-native’, ‘binutils-cross-aarch64’, ‘linux-libc-headers’, ‘libmpc-native’, ‘flex-native’, ‘mpfr-native’, ‘gmp-native’, ‘texinfo-dummy-native’, ‘dbus-native’, ‘gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad’, ‘gstreamer1.0-plugins-base’, ‘gstreamer1.0’, ‘alsa-lib’, ‘pulseaudio’, ‘libgcc’, ‘re2c-native’, ‘gettext-minimal-native’, ‘openssl-native’, ‘xkeyboard-config’, ‘wayland-protocols’, ‘libxml2’, ‘wayland’, ‘libpciaccess’, ‘libpthread-stubs’, ‘bzip2’, ‘libffi’, ‘libpcre’, ‘expat’, ‘autoconf-archive’, ‘libsm’, ‘libx11’, ‘xcb-proto’, ‘xorgproto’, ‘libxau’, ‘libxdmcp’, ‘util-macros’, ‘libxshmfence’, ‘libxxf86vm’, ‘mesa’, ‘xcb-util’, ‘cracklib’, ‘flex’, ‘libxcrypt’, ‘attr’, ‘xz’, ‘ncurses’, ‘libcap-ng’, ‘util-linux-libuuid’, ‘m4-native’, ‘expat-native’, ‘glib-2.0-native’, ‘libusb1’, ‘sbc’, ‘bluez5’, ‘gobject-introspection’, ‘curl’, ‘orc’, ‘tinycompress’, ‘cairo’, ‘imx-gpu-g2d’, ‘pango’, ‘libsndfile1’, ‘libwebp’, ‘librsvg’, ‘linux-imx-headers’, ‘libgudev’, ‘libvorbis’, ‘libogg’, ‘libxv’, ‘iso-codes’, ‘libxrender’, ‘libtheora’, ‘libatomic-ops’, ‘libice’, ‘libxtst’, ‘libtool’, ‘speexdsp’, ‘avahi’, ‘ofono’, ‘perl-native’, ‘python3’, ‘xtrans’, ‘xrandr’, ‘libxfixes’, ‘libxdamage’, ‘python3-native’, ‘libffi-native’, ‘util-linux-native’, ‘gettext-native’, ‘libpcre-native’, ‘readline’, ‘libical’, ‘libidn2’, ‘pixman’, ‘harfbuzz’, ‘fribidi’, ‘libxft’, ‘flac’, ‘libstd-rs’, ‘libcroco’, ‘gdk-pixbuf’, ‘vala’, ‘libxi’, ‘libdaemon’, ‘mobile-broadband-provider-info’, ‘ell’, ‘make-native’, ‘gdbm-native’, ‘gdbm’, ‘libtirpc’, ‘libnsl2’, ‘libxrandr’, ‘libtirpc-native’, ‘util-linux-libuuid-native’, ‘libnsl2-native’, ‘readline-native’, ‘sqlite3-native’, ‘libcap-ng-native’, ‘libpcre2-native’, ‘libunistring’, ‘shared-mime-info’]
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| – The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
| – Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
| – Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
| – Check for working CXX compiler: /home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-sm-linux/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-sm-linux/aarch64-sm-linux-g++ - skipped
| – Detecting CXX compile features
| – Detecting CXX compile features - done
| CMake Error at /home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-sm-linux/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/1.0.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:33 (find_package):
| Could not find a package configuration file provided by “Qt5Multimedia”
| with any of the following names:
|
| Qt5MultimediaConfig.cmake
| qt5multimedia-config.cmake
|
| Add the installation prefix of “Qt5Multimedia” to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
| “Qt5Multimedia_DIR” to a directory containing one of the above files. If
| “Qt5Multimedia” provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
| has been installed.
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
| CMakeLists.txt:66 (find_package)
|
|
| – Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
| See also “/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-sm-linux/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/1.0.0-r0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log”.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-infitron/recipes-app/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code ‘1’
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5602 tasks of which 5601 didn’t need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
Setscene tasks: 2301 of 2301
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 5 seconds

Summary: 1 task failed:
/home/kalpan/silmates-yocto/sm-yocto/build/…/layers/meta-infitron/recipes-app/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app/inf-multipara-mon-fw-ui-app.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.

For above I have already qtmultimedia package and I have already done
DEPENDS += “qtmultimedia”

and
RDEPENDS += “qtmultimedia”

In my application recipe also I run below commands also
bitbake -c cleanaall qtmultimedia
bitbake qtmultimedia

How to fix that configuration error?

also already give prifixpath in my application recipe
